# Buscando por um campo contido em varios models

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Eu tenho um manager no meu projeto, que é para fazer TAGS, e no front do meu sistema o usuario vai pesquisar uma tag, e ele vai retornar tudo relacionado a essa tag.

Segue o models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Noticia(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    autor = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    subtitulo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    fonte = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    veiculo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    data = models.DateTimeField()
    integra = models.TextField()
    curtidas = models.IntegerField()
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Notícia'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Notícias'

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.titulo

class Dados(models.Model):
    dado = models.FloatField()
    texto = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    fonte = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    anotacao = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    relacionado = models.ForeignKey(Noticia, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Dados da noticía'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Dados das notícias'

class Case(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    empresa = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    problemas = models.TextField()
    resultados = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Case'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cases'

class Benchmarking(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    empresa = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    aprendizados = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Benchmarking'
```

A TAG, é este "tags = TaggableManager()". E coloquei ela em varias tables.

Quero digitar por exemplo: Overflow, e ele vai retornar todas as esses itens que tem cadastrado a tag overflow

Minha view filtrando as tags: (ta do jeito que era antigamente, filtrando somente em noticias)

```
def getdb(request):
    noticias = Noticia.objects.all()
    _tags = request.GET.get('search')
    tags = ''
    if _tags:
        tags = _tags.split(',')

    noticias = noticias.filter(tags__name__in=tags)
```

Comment: Certo, mas ai vc apenas registrou o campo de Tags em seus modelos , onde vc vai de fato incluir tags ou ate mesmo realizar pesquisas baseadas em tags é na view. 
Como vc esta lidando com sua View ?

Comment: No admin, quando vai cadastrar algum desses itens, ja cadastra as tags tb

Comment: Sim , mas para exibilas em uma view vc precisa 'filtrar' seus modelos baseados nas tags e assim retornar uma query contendo as mesmas

Comment: Desculpa, editei com a view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder filtrar de forma eficiente vc tem de passar o objeto resultante de sua pesquisa como contexto para sua view.

**views.py**

```
def getdb(request):
    _tags = request.GET.get('search')
    if _tags:
        tags = _tags.split(',')

    noticias = Noticia.objects.all().filter(tags__name__in=[_tag])
    #Pesquisa todos os objetos Noticia que contem sua tag

    context = {
        'noticias': noticias,
    }

    return render(request, 'seuhtml.html', context)
```

Por fim basta exibir seu objeto resultante em seu template

**seuhtml.html**

```
{% for item in noticias %}
    {{item.autor}}
    {{item.titulo}}
    {{item.subtitulo}}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Para filtrar por todos os objetos em seu modelo é preciso manter um relacionamento entre eles. Como em seu objteto `dados`, visto que existe o relacionamento `relacionado = models.ForeignKey(Noticia, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` o mesmo se torna disponivel em sua view:

```
{% for item in noticias %}
    {{item.autor}}
    {{item.titulo}}
    {{item.subtitulo}}
    {{item.dados.texto}}
    {{item.dados.fonte}}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Estabeleça a devida relação entre os modelos nos quais vc quer filtrar e os mesmos se tornarão disponiveis por sua query principal:

`noticias = Noticia.objects.all().filter(tags__name__in=[_tag])`.

Note que uma vez que as relações estão bem estabelecidas voce só precisará ter tag em sua noticia (`tags = TaggableManager()`) visto que é apenas por ela que se baseará para obter o restante.

Para mais informações sobre relacionamentos [visite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

Para mais informaçoes sobre as tags e a bilioteca que voce usa [acesse](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

Comment: mas eu preciso buscar mais itens alem de noticias

Comment: Certo , adicionada as alterações

Comment: a pesquisa ta retornando vazia olha só: <QuerySet []>